# MongoDB: Too many connections created from mongos to shards while building index

Tags: mongodb

We'v set up sharded cluster with replica set for each shard in our production ENV. Last night we encountered a issue while connecting to the cluster and issuing building index command through mongo shell , by connecting to the mongos instance , not directly to specific shard.

The issue is : once starting building the index, connections created from mongos to this shard increases rapidly and 'too many connections' errors show up in the primary shard's log file very soon. 
The below is link for primary shard's log summary:
[At the very beginning for index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8aO7.png)
Then very soon, the connections numbers reached to 10000:
[Connection limit exceeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XC8m.png)

From the three mongos' log, all the connections are initiated from mongos. We have googled and find related issue link as : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-28822
But there is no trigger conditions. And the same time, I tried to reproduce the question in test ENV ,but not occurred again. So, please help.

here is configurations for mongos:
[mongos' configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1VPU.png)
and here is for shard:
[primary shard's configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDcMT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.
It was because the index creation issued by `mongorestore` command was foreground, not background. I mistook the way which mongorestore took and not checked the meta file for the table schema.